HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T " leaves oddly formatted date/time stamps
I am following this page to add date/time stamps to ~/.bash_history.  Specifically, I added HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T " to my ~/.bashrc.  Running exec bash didn't cause the date/time stamp to be added, but source ~/.bashrc did.  However, the format of the date/time stamps is not in accordance with HISTTIMEFORMAT.  I expect prefixes like #2024-06-26 10:45:32.  Here are some examples what they actually look like:
#1719413058
#1719413062
#1719413065
#1719413146
#1719413148
#1719413149
#1719413149
#1719413228
#1719413275
#1719413279
#1719413293

What am I doing wrong?

The format in HISTTIMEFORMAT is the one used for output, by the history command. In the history file itself bash is only going to use its internal format (comment character+ Unix timestamp), as you see.
